# Is it a good idea, to use the with-statement with the context?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, with-statement

If I have a rendering function in my game for example, that is called at a pretty high rate (determined by requestAnimationFrame), like this for example:

```
function render() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(player.x, player.y, player.size / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#6f00ff";
    ctx.fill();
}
```

Why not simply just wrap it all up inside a with-statement?

```
function render() {
    with (ctx) {
        clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        beginPath();
        arc(player.x, player.y, player.size / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        fillStyle = "#6f00ff";
        fill();
    }
}
```

Is this a good idea/practice? If not, why not?

EDIT ///////

For you guys that have no idea what HTML5 canvas is:

canvas is a reference to a `<canvas>` DOM (Document Object Model) element, might look something like this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
```

and ctx is a reference to:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Answer (score 2):

It's generally not considered a good idea because in the code it's not obvious if:

```
canvas.width = ctx.canvas.width ?
player.x = ctx.player.x ?
```

Also, what if you defined `ctx` as:

```
var ctx = {
    clearRect: function(){/* some code */},
    beginPath: function(){/* some code */},
    arc: function(){/* some code */},
    fill: function(){/* some code */},
}
```

And then when you do:

```
with (ctx) {
    fillStyle = "#6f00ff";
}
```

Expecting to set `ctx.fillStyle` but it doesn't. Instead is merely sets a global variable `fillStyle`.

Because it makes readability worse, `with` is generally considered a buggy feature and is always avoided.

Comment: What? Obviously the ctx object is an instance of `CanvasRenderingContext2D`, and even more obviously does *not* contain a player property

Comment: @Murplyx—it's not obvious to everyone, and may not be to those who might have to maintain the code.

Comment: @Murplyx: Is it really obvious that the `CanvasRenderingContext2D` object does not have a `player` property? What if the library is updated to contain a `player` property and the person who added it forgot about that `with` statement? It is for this reason that `with` is considered a boobytrap and is disabled in strict mode.

Comment: I made an edit to make it more clear

Comment: Why would "someone" update it so that it contains a player property?

Comment: @Murplyx: It's called maintenance, people add features to code when asked by their boss. If your question is specifically about "is it a good idea to use `with` with canvas 2D context?" then that is another question. However this question is a bit more general: "is it a good idea to use `with` like the example code above?" to which the answer is no.

Comment: @Murplyx:  Even if it was specifically about canvas context, note that standards change every few years. The canvas 2D context object may gain new properties. It may not be `player` but it may be something else like `x` or `cursor` or something else. Which would require you to correctly guess a safe variable name to use. A better solution is to simply avoid `with`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) isn't a good idea at all, as a matter of fact you shouldn't use it. It's useful in few situations and yours isn't one of those limited few :)

On the MDN page a **pro** and a **contra** are described:

**pro**

> **Pro:** The with statement can help reduce file size by reducing the need to repeat a lengthy object reference without performance penalty. The scope chain change required by 'with' is not computationally expensive. Use of 'with' will relieve the interpreter of parsing repeated object references. Note, however, that in many cases this benefit can be achieved by using a temporary variable to store a reference to the desired object.

**contra**

> **Contra:** The with statement forces the specified object to be searched first for all name lookups. Therefore all identifiers that aren't members of the specified object will be found more slowly in a 'with' block. Where performance is important, 'with' should only be used to encompass code blocks that access members of the specified object.

Basically, what they are saying is that as long as you use the `with()` construct correctly you'll be fine but if you miss one key it'll be much slower. The chances of that happening might be 0% but if there's a bug in your program - this could catch on to it and cause a bug you would have difficulties finding when debugging.

**TL;DR;**

Unless you know exactly what you're doing and not using ecmascript 5 strict mode, don't use `with();` as it's more of a risky tradeoff than a safe construct.